# SharePoint Online - Authentication issue with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, authentication

I am not able to open my SharePoint online site in SharePoint Designer 2013. It is giving below authentication error while trying to open the site "**Your account is in a bad state. Please sign-in to this account online to address the issue**". Site is working fine in browser and I am also able to access it via browser. I am site owner. Please suggest some solutions.

[image]

Comment: Experienced the same issue after changing my password

Answer (score 2):

To use SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint Online, you can download and install the following updates in order:
[Download and Install SharePoint Designer 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35491)

[Download and install SharePoint Designer SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42015)

[Install 2016 Feb(2) update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50706)

[Install 2016 Ang(8) update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53364)

After installing the above updates, test again, it should work well.

Reference:
[SharePoint | Online | Best Practice | How to install SharePoint Designer for connecting to SharePoint Online](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/24150607-ff54-4ab8-9ba9-d3175286de5f/sharepoint-online-best-practice-how-to-install-sharepoint-designer-for-connecting-to?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing)

Comment: Thank you Kally for solution ! But it was working fine before few days. I am working on it from last 5-6 months. After some security changes (getting code on mobile number from Microsoft) at organization level, it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me via this article:  [SharePoint Designer and Modern Authentication](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-designer-and-modern-authentication/ba-p/382774)

- Add Reg_Dword - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity\EnableADAL = 1
- SPD 2013 update:  https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3114721
- MSO.DLL:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4475607
- CSI.DLL:  https://support.microsoft.com/help/3172545
- ADAL.DLL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3085565

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to supply an App Password for SPD to work with SPO.

https://portal.office.com/account/

Security & privacy (left nav)
Click on Additional security verification
Click on Create and manage app passwords

On the next page I created an entry titled SPD*Year* and used that password for SPD.

SPD login:
L: myEmail@MyCompany.com
P: app password

Comment: Never use app passwords! This is a significant security risk and is not required for SharePoint Designer to access SPO. App passwords should be disabled on tenants due to their security risk.