# Unable to open SharePoint online site in SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am getting below error message while trying to access SharePoint online site in SharePoint designer.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging via your browser?

Comment: Yes, I am able to login in Web browser

Comment: Do you use multi-factor authentication with your account?

Comment: @user3210176 have you check [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/262672/sharepoint-online-authentication-issue-with-sharepoint-designer?rq=1) ?

Answer (score 2):

Follow [SharePoint Designer and Modern Authentication](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-designer-and-modern-authentication/ba-p/382774). This guide is written by Microsoft and will allow you to connect to SPO with Modern Auth from Designer.

Comment: The issue resolved by disabling Multifactor authentication  in azure active directory. Below things i tried from my end to resolve the issue.

1. Access the azure active directory 

2. Access my organization AD, click on properties, then click on Manage security defaults, the click on "No" for enable security defaults option.

Comment: That's a really, really bad idea. Don't work around the problem! MFA is a baseline requirement.